# Moving bones out from a center point

Tags: animation

[image]I am trying to move these bones out from a center point (the center platform). I'd like to animate them moving out from the center platform (center platform doesn't move. All of the squares are separate objects and the bones are connected to their respective platform. I also parented all of the bones to the center one.

I'm currently stuck trying to figure out how to move all of them out in pose mode. I tried searching and found a couple things to try involving the pivot point, but they don't seem to work. I just end up scaling up the platforms instead of actually moving them away from the center point.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks bros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 3 steps to this:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. scale with all selected and center one being the active element
   [image]